# "Failed building wheel for psycopg2" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2

I'm attempting to make a website with a few others for the first time, and have run into a weird error when trying to use Django/Python/VirtualEnv. I've found solutions to this problem for other operating systems, such as Ubuntu, but can't find any good solutions for Mac.

This is the relevant code being run:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After running that block, I get the following errors:

> AssertionError
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for django-toolbelt
>    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2

...

> AssertionError
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for psycopg2
>    Failed to build django-toolbelt psycopg2

I believe I've installed the "django-toolbelt" and "psycopg2", so I'm not sure why it would be failing.

The only difference I can think of is that I did not use the command

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

as was instructed for Ubuntu usage as I believe that installing postgresql with brew took care of the header.

Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: My answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl

Comment: This solution worked for wheel, venv & pip - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596814/984471

Comment: running sudo apt-get install libpq-dev and pip install psycopg2-binary worked for me, also after that i could run pipenv install psycopg2

Answer (score 111):

**For MacOS users**

After trying all the above methods (which did not work for me on MacOS 10.14), that one worked :

- Install openssl with `brew install openssl` if you don't have it already.
- add openssl path to `LIBRARY_PATH` :

```sh
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

- install psycopg2 with pip `pip3 install psycopg2`

Comment: Worked for me after ld: library not found for -lssl

Comment: tried all above answers, after that I applied this answer. worked on Big Sur 11.2.3
thanks a lot 
Note: it worked after I ran `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: For macOS on Apple Silicon, use `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib` instead.

Comment: I faced same problem specially in mac OS.X, yes, it's actually a SSL problem. Fixed after exporting the ssl.

Answer (score 94):

I had the same problem on Arch linux. I think that it's not an OS dependant problem. Anyway, I fixed this by finding the outdated packages and updating then.

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip list --outdated
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me on OS X, thanks! (OS X 10.11.2, Python 3.5.1, pip 7.1.2)

Comment: Worked for me as well. I believe for my specific virtualenv that the `wheel` package was out of date, as `setuptools` was fine. So it may just be necessary to run `pip install --upgrade wheel`.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score 61):

I was also getting same error.
Using Python 3.7.3 and pip 19.1.1.

I used following command.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

Comment: For python 3.8 use pip install psycopg2-binary

Answer (score 22):

### TDLR

If you aren't used to installing Python C-extensions, and `psycopg2` isn't a core part of your work, try

```sh
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

#### Building Locally

psycopg2 is a C-extension, so it requires compilation when being installed by pip.  The Build Prerequisites section of the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites) explain what must be done to make installation via pip possible.  In summary (for psycopg 2.8.5):

- a C compiler must be installed on the machine
- the Python header files must be installed
- the `libpq` header files must be installed
- the `pg_config` program must be installed (it usually comes with the `libpq` headers) and on `$PATH`.

With these prerequisites satisfied, `pip install psycopg2` ought to succeed.

#### Installing pre-compiled wheels

Alternatively, `pip` can install [pre-compiled binaries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi) so that compilation (and the associated setup) is not required.  They can be installed like this:

```sh
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

The docs note that

> The psycopg2-binary package is meant for beginners to start playing with Python and PostgreSQL without the need to meet the build requirements.

but I would suggest that `psycopg2-binary` is often *good enough* for local development work if you are not using psycopg2 directly, but just as a dependency.

#### Concluding advice

Read the informative [installation documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html), not only to overcome installation issues but also to understand the impact of using the pre-compiled binaries in some scenarios.

Answer (score 18):

I had same problem and this appears to be a Mojave Issue, I was able to resolve with:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Thanks @farzad-farazmand. Helped me to to install `pip install psycopg2==2.5.4` after running you above command on macOS 10.14.6.

Answer (score 17):

For MacOS users, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra) question has the correct solution:

install command line tools if necessary:

`xcode-select --install`

then

`env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 15):

For Mac OS X users:

**1. First check your postgresql path by running this command in terminal:**

```
pg_config
```

If this fails lookup how to add pg_config to your path.

**2. Next install Xcode Tools by running this command in terminal:**

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you have both those sorted out now try to install psycopg2 again

Comment: Both are fine but still got the problem

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing the same after running all the above commands, but the following two commands worked for me:

1. **Instead of pip, use this:**

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

2. **then run this command:**

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: `apt` recommends `postgresql-doc-12` instead of `libpq-dev` now. `psycopg2` installs successfully with either of these installed.

Answer (score 6):

On OS X, I was able to solve this by simply upgrading wheel before installing psycopg2:

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

Answer (score 5):

For OSX Sierra users, it seems that an xcode update is the solution: [Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install... Is this because of Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra)

Comment: I tried close to 10 different things (including building postgres from source, linking the libs, etc. to my path, practically reimaging my machine) this was all it was!

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the above solutions but they did not work for me. What I did was change the psycopg2 version in my requirements.txt file from `psycopg2==2.7.4` to `psycopg2==2.7.6`

Comment: Are you describing what you did but then failed? That would not answer this question and be more of a new question. Or is this an answer, as in "Everything described here failed, but the folowing works."?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I think they are saying that the proposed solutions didn't work, so they posted what did work for them. That said, they basically have the same solution as Utsav Preet from July 7, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by installing `python3.7-dev`: `sudo apt install python3.7-dev`, based on the [link](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/900#issuecomment-513206232).

- Python: 3.7
- Ubuntu: 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Thanks to this I realised I had to use python3.12-dev.

Answer (score 1):

Is your error message complete? the most encountered reason for failing to install psycopg2 on mac from pip is pg_config is not in path.
by the way, using macports or fink to install psycopg2 is more recommended way, so you don't have to worry about pg_config, libpq-dev and python-dev.

plus, are using Python 3.5? then upgrage your wheel to > 0.25.0 using pip.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but the answers above didn't work for me.
So this is what I did in my requirements.txt
**psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1** and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on several packages, including psycopg2, numpy, and pandas. I simply removed the version from the requirements.txt file, and it worked.

So instead of **psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1** I just had **psycopg2-binary**.

Comment: I had these packages in my project and have problem to active pipenv virtual environment after updating to python 3.8, all my attempts failed to activate pipenv virtual environment, but after removing version number after pandas, psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary in requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python3.X-dev
```

where X is the sub version,

these should be followed by :

```
  pip install --upgrade wheel
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
  pip install psycopg2
```

Enjoy !!!

Comment: This was it! The python3.X-dev was the one thing that got it working for me on Linux Mint! I was so frustrated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for development environment but if you are deploying on server say, Heroku. Just add below line in the *requirements.txt* of your project.

**django-heroku==0.3.1**

As this package itself will install the required packages like *psycopg2* on server deployment.So let the server(heroku) should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by updating/installing vs_BuildTools. The link to the software was given in the error itself.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n00pq.jpg)

Comment: Please post the error logs as text, instead of posting the link to picture.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I though the LIBRARY_PATH would work but unfortunately it didn't.

Using Homebrew on MacOS Silicon, the following workaround did the trick for me:

`LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include pip install -r requirements.txt # or pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 0):

On windows I've managed to solve this by adding C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib to LIB env variable