# Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, psycopg2

I am working on a project for one of my lectures and I need to download the package psycopg2 in order to work with the postgresql database in use. Unfortunately, when I try to pip install psycopg2 the following error pops up:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

I fixed this by installing Command Line Tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

then installing openssl via Homebrew and manually linking my homebrew-installed openssl to pip:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2
```

on macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Comment: The xcode install was enough for me to get it working. Good looking out.

Comment: I also got it after dev-tools install

Comment: for me also worked , thanks and what will be the permanent solution?

Comment: Works on Catalina as well

Comment: as of May 2022 and brew, this works for me: `LDFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 64):

Try installing it with:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: Is this interchangeable with `psycopg2`?

Comment: @pkaramol yes it is

Comment: Make sure your pip is up to date also `pip install -U pip` or you will get errors like `vcvarsall.bat not found`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/ "The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources."

Comment: this is a good answer for fairly recent `psycopg2`, but older versions (e.g. 2.8.6) are not provided by the packager and the wheel must be built locally.

Answer (score 48):

```
brew install postgresql
```

If postgresql exist then run:

```
brew upgrade postgresql
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

In venv:

```
env LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip install psycopg2==2.8.4
```

If you need use only the command `pip install psycopg2` export the path in macOSX:

```
export LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, using brew install and then type in the "env =" in my terminal. However this is complete dark magic, can anyone explain why this was necessary and what it actually did? Thanks! For information, in May 2020 the mac version is Catalina.

Comment: This is the only trick that worked for me :)

Comment: `brew install postgresql` did the trick for me!

Answer (score 22):

I fixed it with:

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, on Catalina. I'm using Python version 3.8.2, where I have `pyenv` managing my Python environments and installations. Your solution worked from me, but I executed: `$ python -m pip install psycopg2` instead of how others used `$ pip install psycopg2`, which we might not know which interpreter we are using and installing. This will ensure pip we will be using and installing with my default python interpreter, which is version 3.8.2 for me.

Comment: That export will need be added to my .bashrc forever?

Answer (score 13):

Running into a similar problem using pipenv install psycopg2:

> ld: library not found for -lssl', '    clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)', "    error:
>   command 'clang' failed with exit status 1", '
>   ----------------------------------------',

I tried all of the recommendations above and none of them worked. I'd faced this problem in another virtualenv a few months ago and remembered reading something about this being a [psycopg2 version issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/aah5da/pipenv_install_psycopg2_installs_package_but_cant/). So I tried installing with 2.7.1 and 2.8.3 and both still failed. Somehow version 2.7.7 worked:

```
pipenv install psycopg2==2.7.7
```

Wish I had time to look into this further to understand what's really happening. But for now I don't and this worked.

Answer (score 12):

For Mac OS 11.06 BigSur M1 ship, installing under a pyenv

```
brew reinstall libpq
brew reinstall openssl
```

Or install if its not already the case

```
brew info libpq
brew info openssl
```

Combine the 2 exported output logically, from

> For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
>
> export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
>
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"

> ...
> export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"

> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"

into

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

Then you can reinstall psycopg2, forcing the recompile, otherwise you will have [this problem at runtime](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1208)

```
pip uninstall psycopg2 
pip install psycopg2 --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Install/update Xcode developer tools

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
2. Query postgres path

   ```
   find / -name pg_config  2>/dev/null
   ```
3. Install psycopg2, use the path you got in **step 2**. Mine was '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/bin/pg_config'

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/bin/ pip install psycopg2
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Well, tons of different options didn't work for me, but finally!

First, try this:

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

At the end of the reinstallation process you will get basically the following lines within **Caveats** section, which I've put in the zshrc config file since I use macOS Big Sur (version 11.1) and zsh terminal.

Open zshrc or other config file specific to your system:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Paste the following lines at the end (or change these commands accordingly to the **Caveats** you've got), just keep in mind that OpenSSL provided by Homebrew might conflict with the system's one (I've got a warning that macOS provides LibreSSL) but it worked well anyway:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

Save the file and exit by pressing **^X** and confirming with **Yes**.

Hopefully you can now install psycopg2:

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

I'm still not sure what was the root cause of the problem, it just appeared suddenly when I tried to reinstall pipenv for my project (maybe some recent system updates).

Comment: Same here! Your suggestion was worked! Thanks a lot for saving my day.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the openssl package is not installed. Try installing it and `pip install` again. I'm not a macos user, but I believe that [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) simplifies package management on that platform.

You might also need to install the Python development and postgresql development packages.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (on a terminal):

```
find / -name pg_config  2>/dev/null
```

then add the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/
```

os version: MacOs Sierra

I hope this helps.

Comment: This assumes you have installed Postgres.app on your mac and not using mac ports, home brew, the EnterpriseDB installer or another way of packaging/installing your postgresql server on your mac, yes?

Comment: Oh also the original question was about missing -lssl library and then "clang", but not the pg_config tool. Clang is in Xcode, the other thing is in the openssl library. user @zganger has the right answer to this question.

(I got here looking for the pg_config issue, so your answer helped me a ton, but it's not what the question asked).

Answer (score 1):

Old, but for folks using pipenv, I resolved this issue by looking at my dependency graph `pipenv graph --reverse` and noticing it required `psycopg2-binary==2.8.2`.  Running `pipenv install psycopg2-binary` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" \
brew upgrade openssl
```

Then I could install `psycopg2`

Answer (score 1):

try this -->pip install psycopg2-binary

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On my scenario, it was performed on:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.1
BuildVersion:   21C52
```

- I proceed to install the following libraries by `brew`command:

```bash
brew install openssl libpq
```

- Set specific variables:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

- Proceed to install the python package `psycopg2-binary` via `pip3`:

```bash
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

If you are wondering why it is necessary to set those specific variables, take a look in the docs of the package via `brew info` command:

```bash
brew info openssl
brew info libpq
```

When the outcome is displayed, look for this sentence:

```
...
For compilers to find libpq you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
...
For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
...
```

Thats why, when `pip` is installing a package, needs a reference where to look for the libraries/compilers.

A perfect place to set this variables would be `~/.bashrc`, for future installations regarding `postgres` and `ssl`:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to faff around with `brew`, here's the "MacOS-only solution":

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

After this, `pip` will gladly install `psycopg2` from the source. Works with "Mojave" (macOS 10.14).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing:
`pip install psycopg2-binary`
it works

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error on macOS Big Sur (11.5.1) and Python 3.9.6.

It turned out, the psycopg2 (as well as pandas) versions I was using were too old. The error disappeared and `pip install` started working fine after upgrading the above packages.

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12854#issuecomment-619213863

In general, if the solutions suggested here by others don't help, try upgrading the troubling python package.

Answer (score -4):

As per current/todey condition -
only solution for this is -
uninstall your python 3.8 or 3.9 or so on
and install ptyhon 3.7.4

Comment: Given this question was asked in 2016, I doubt very much that "uninstall Python 3.8/3.9 and install Python 3.7" is a solution to the OP's problem

Comment: This is so wrong. I ran @Apurva's answer and it worked for me. I'm using Catalina, and I have multiple Python versions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722268/3255762