# Can't install psycopg2 in mac os with pip

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install psycopg2 into virtualenv using pip and getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Tried to google `lssl` library for python and can't find any mentions of this error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
pip 8.1.2
python 2.7.10
virtualenv 12.0.7
macos 10.12.1
```

**Update:** Actually looks like this question is a duplicate of this one: [Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install... Is this because of Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra) The solution from that question helped me. The issue was in missing xcode-cli tools and `xcode-select --install` fixed my problem.

Comment: Try installing openssl. I suspect that will clear it up.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono tried `pip install pyopenssl`. There is no changes.

Answer (score 2):

So actually this question is a duplicate of this one: [Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install... Is this because of Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra)

In my case `xcode-select --install` fixed the problem. I suppose I got this issue because I updated my Xcode to the new version which was released yesterday.