# psycopg2 can't install in virtualenv 2.7 in Mojave - macOS - 10.14.5

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

I am having this error:

```
 cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "[path]/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8n/zd44l25535b8kfhz1cfdx7980000gn/T/pip-install-nVe8Y3/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8n/zd44l25535b8kfhz1cfdx7980000gn/T/pip-record-NVUuR_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /[path]/venv/include/site/python2.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8n/zd44l25535b8kfhz1cfdx7980000gn/T/pip-install-nVe8Y3/psycopg2/
```

When I am installing psycopg2 in macOS not in virtualenv - this helped me:
[psycopg2 sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra)

Answer by @zganger

But when I am in virtualenv 2.7 (venv) - nothing works, none of the answers even in that post. I was trying to solve this for a week and no luck at all.

Not sure what I else I can do.

When you create the virtualenv and just run these commands, both are failing on psycopg2, if I install any other package all is working nicely except psycopg2.

```
1. pip install django-toolbelt
2. pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: What error do you get when installing in virtual env?

Comment: Have you installed PostgreSQL? `brew install postgresql`

Comment: @hoefling The error above in the question - ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: @wencakisa yes 1st installed via brew and then created the virtualenv, activate it and then django-toolbelt - error, so did pip install psycopg2 - error as well...

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python

Comment: @Radek What about `xcode-select --install` ?

Comment: @VigneshAmmasi Mostly that is for linux - but I saw there for mac - and those I have already tried especially exporting path which is to Postgres.app - and no luck - it works for my mac not in virtualenv - but when I create the virtualenv, it does not work - it worked in High Sierra not Mojave.

Comment: @wencakisa I have tried that also "command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates" - and I have no any other updates...

Comment: @wencakisa On 15th of July new command line tools were released and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have tried everything what I could and what I have found is my Mojave version was

```
10.14.5
```

and that was till July 14th 2019 up to date version and it did not work.

I have updated to the newest version

```
10.14.6 and Command Line Tools 10.3
```

which was released today (July 15th 2019), and it worked perfectly.

Probably there is an issue in previous command line tools or the 10.14.5 version of Mojave

This update worked:
[image: Command Line Tools 10.3 / Mojave 10.14.d]