# How to fix error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python." when trying to install django-heroku using pip

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am trying to install django-heroku using pip, but it keeps running into an error.

I have seen suggestions telling me to make sure my Python version in Heroku is up to date. I have already done that. After pushing to Heroku master, I ran the install command, but it gives me the following errors.

```
pip install django-heroku
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Users/user/Dev/trydjango/new_env/bin/python -c 'import
sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'/private/var/folders/xl/s533dc515qs8sd3tpg7y5ty80000gp/T/pip-
install-xqsix26g/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';

egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd:
/private/var/folders/xl/s533dc515qs8sd3tpg7y5ty80000gp/T/pip-
install-xqsix26g/psycopg2/
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-
info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-
info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add t .   he directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable
path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please
install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file
(also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I have fixed this by running `env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2
` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800677/4270698 on MacOS Catalina

Comment: I had a similar error, I fixed it using `pip install -U setuptools`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the package containing the executable *pg_config*.

A prior answer should have details you need:  *[pg_config executable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found)*