# COLAB ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, google-colaboratory, enchant

Could anyone please help me to fix this? I am trying to install pyenchant in colab to perform a possible suggestion if a word is spelled wrongly. I would like to use `pyenchant`.
This is what I tried;

```
!pip install pyenchant==1.6.8
```

but it output the following error;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

My idea is to get some possible suggestion if a word is wrong,
I plan to do the following

```
import enchant
test = enchant.Dict("en_US")
test.suggest("Posible")
```

Could anyone suggest how can I achieve this? I am working on colab. Please help me on how to install `pyenchant` in colab or any other possible way I can achieve possible suggestion if a word is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install with apt first

```
!apt install enchant
```

Then with pip

```
!pip install pyenchant
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility based on NLTK without enchant is NLTK's words corpus

```py
>>> from nltk.corpus import words
>>> "would" in words.words()
True
>>> "could" in words.words()
True
>>> "should" in words.words()
True
>>> "I" in words.words()
True
>>> "you" in words.words()
True
```

Or if you still want to use enchant
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444274/11339475
Have look at this solution, It has already been addressed.