# Pip Install magpie error: Command Errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip, magpie

```
(base) Niklass-MacBook-Pro:~ niklasroberts$ pip3 install magpie
Collecting magpie
  Using cached magpie-0.1.0.tar.gz (56 kB)
Collecting argparse==1.2.1
  Using cached argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69 kB)
Collecting backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
  Using cached backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2.tar.gz (5.2 kB)
Collecting filemagic==1.6
  Using cached filemagic-1.6.tar.gz (16 kB)
Collecting markdown2==2.2.1
  Using cached markdown2-2.2.1.zip (138 kB)
Collecting py-bcrypt==0.4
  Using cached py-bcrypt-0.4.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting pyPdf==1.13
  Using cached pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz (35 kB)
Collecting sh==1.09
  Using cached sh-1.09.tar.gz (26 kB)
Collecting tornado==3.2
  Using cached tornado-3.2.tar.gz (400 kB)
Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2
  Using cached wsgiref-0.1.2.zip (37 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/niklasroberts/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-install-0onf8qup/wsgiref/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-install-0onf8qup/wsgiref/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-8o9qy2d_
         cwd: /private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-install-0onf8qup/wsgiref/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-install-0onf8qup/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
      File "/private/var/folders/m6/zp9c98hs2q3b8pvjz2gj6nzw0000gn/T/pip-install-0onf8qup/wsgiref/ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
        print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed.")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am running on mac os X Mojave 10.14.6. I am a command line newbie, and am pretty lost. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444207/how-to-fix-error-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-when-t) and used brew install postgresql, but that didn't seem to solve any of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

[`magpie` 0.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/magpie/0.1.0/), released at Jul 16, 2014. [Declares compatibility](https://github.com/charlesthomas/magpie/blob/a6ffcefaf24c5fd0b886cb85a2a6ed37f77d39ba/setup.py#L19) only with Python 2.7.

[`wsgiref` 0.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/wsgiref/0.1.2/), released at Jun 12, 2006. Declares compatibility with Python versions < 3.2. But the code in `ez_setup` is not compatible with Python 3 at all.

Bottom line: you're trying to install packages that are too old, they should only be installed with Python 2.7.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I found out that the error I was running into was that I was trying to install private software, so once I gained access it all worked.