# Error installing psycopg2 python 3.7 on macos 10.15

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos-catalina

I tried `pip3 install psycopg2`

Got these errors, unable to understand what I need to do.

Please help.

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.7.3.1   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/fb/15c687eda2f925f0ff59373063fdb408471b4284714a7761daaa65c01f15/psycopg2-2.7.3.1.tar.gz Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/amolchakane/Desktop/Projects/kisanoauth/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pycharm-packaging/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pycharm-packaging/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pip-record-f050z4mz/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/amolchakane/Desktop/Projects/kisanoauth/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pycharm-packaging/psycopg2/
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/tests
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.7.3.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110500 -DHAVE_LO64=1
-I/Users/amolchakane/Desktop/Projects/kisanoauth/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.5_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.5_1/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/amolchakane/Desktop/Projects/kisanoauth/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pycharm-packaging/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pycharm-packaging/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/c7/wshj0hq9637_ddn00y_52y7c0000gp/T/pip-record-f050z4mz/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/amolchakane/Desktop/Projects/kisanoauth/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar The project is using `django` framework and `psycopg2` is needed as requirement. So I have added `django` tag.
Also I have formatted the error properly. Can you help now?

Comment: This fixed it for me on Mac OSX 10.15.5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621735/9610200

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could solve this problem by installing the binary library which is indicated in the comment above. (It just has a typo error)

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

The error from Amol Chakane refers but to a PIP error referring to a package that wasn't found because of misspelling.

Make sure also that your `pip` command is referring to the right Python version. In my case, I'm using an environment with Python 3 and I don't need to specify `pip3` but just `pip`

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Django (as I am), you may want to try psycopg2-binary instead. It's meant for developers and testing, but not production use. I'm using the same version of Python (3.7), Django version 2.2.6 in a virtual environment on Mac OS Mojave. I couldn't install pyscopg2 on my system either.

pip install pyscopg2-binary

These are the docs that I used to help me figure this out: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source
https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Comment: I already tried that and it gives me error.
`Amols-Air:~ amolchakane$ pip install pyscopg2-binary
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyscopg2-binary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyscopg2-binary`
And I want it to be used for Production as well.

Comment: It seems like the xcrun and gcc errors are significant. @Housemd fixed his own solution with the same type of xcrun and gcc errors here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a