# Is there any problem installing psycopg2 in virtualenv on MacOS catalina with PostgreSQL 12.1 installed?

Tags: postgresql, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2, macos-catalina

I am having this message:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/mohsen/.virtualenvs/jalas-env/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/vh/0_hbs48171574k5y9pb97st80000gn/T/pip-install-y72dxnyb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/vh/0_hbs48171574k5y9pb97st80000gn/T/pip-install-y72dxnyb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/vh/0_hbs48171574k5y9pb97st80000gn/T/pip-wheel-51dm_zyp --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/vh/0_hbs48171574k5y9pb97st80000gn/T/pip-install-y72dxnyb/psycopg2/
  Complete output (144 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
  psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1714:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
      ret = 1;
            ^
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1819:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  3 warnings generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
  In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o
  In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  .
  .
  .
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
  In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o
  In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
  In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:27:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
  In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
  In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
  In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
  ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
  static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
              ^
  1 warning generated.
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
  clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
```

I get this error installing psycopg2 in macOS Catalina on virtualenv using pip.

I have already installed PostgreSQL 12.1 following [this link](https://medium.com/@Umesh_Kafle/postgresql-and-postgis-installation-in-mac-os-87fa98a6814d) and also created some database on it following [this link](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/install-and-configure-posgresql-for-django).

So does anybody have any idea what is wrong with psycopg2 not installing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install... Is this because of Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpsycopg%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pip install Django psycopg2` instead of `pip install psycopg2` and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue namely `ld: library not found for -lssl`.

But I had openSSL installed. For for me it amounted to setting the following, before running `pip install`, as per https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795#issuecomment-337006164

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the OpenSSL library or its header files installed.