# can not install psycopg2 on macOS Catalina

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, macos

when installing psycopg2 in my Django project

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.*
```

I get this error :

```
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
```

I tried the answer to the following question: [Is there any problem installing psycopg2 in virtualenv on MacOS catalina with PostgreSQL 12.1 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065263/is-there-any-problem-installing-psycopg2-in-virtualenv-on-macos-catalina-with-po)
 but I still get the same error

Comment: Try installing `psycopg2-binary` instead

Comment: Yes I do it, and it ok,  but i can't install my second library django-heroku this library look for psycopg2

Comment: Try `pip install django-heroku --no-dependencies` and then install the other dependencies yourself. The other dependencies are "dj-database-url>=0.5.0" and "whitenoise"

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? Did the suggestion by @IainShelvington work?

Comment: yes I create my project with pycharm IDE, by default pycharm create a virtual environments with project interpreter, in my case this project interpreter is python 3.7 and pip 10.0.1

Comment: I try pip install django-heroku --no-dependencies , and when I try pip install dj-database-url>=0.5.0 , I get this error : "django-heroku 0.3.1 requires psycopg2, which is not installed."

Answer (score 5):

Installing `psycopg2-binary` worked for me.

Comment: Note the caveat about psycopg2-binary: "The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources." https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 3.8.x then the support for the same was added in psycopg2 2.8.x. I faced the same problem but worked out fine once I switched to python 3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Installing PostgreSQL fixed it for me, but the error was not exactly the same.
Anyways, give it a try:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

if this does not help you try this:

```
xcode-select --install
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

another way is this:

```
brew install postgresql
pip install --no-binary :all: psycopg2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).