# MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 Flask-Mysqldb pip install error

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql

I tried every method on the web but I wasn't be able to install flask-mysql db via terminal. I always keep gettin this error.

```
"ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-install-dfntjsy3/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-install-dfntjsy3/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-record-wl2niv7i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output."
```

Edit: error string formatted for readability:

```
#"ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
    #/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 

        import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
        sys.argv[0] = '/private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-install-dfntjsy3/mysqlclient/setup.py' 
        __file__=     '/private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-install-dfntjsy3/mysqlclient/setup.py'
        f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
        code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
        f.close();
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))

    #install 
    #--record /private/var/folders/78/j5s7f35s7tbfp971ftclk9d00000gn/T/pip-record-wl2niv7i/install-record.txt 
    #--single-version-externally-managed 
    #--compile 
    #--install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/mysqlclient 

#Check the logs for full command output."
```

Comment: just to confirm, you're using PIP to install?

Comment: does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800677/3220135 (installing command line tools that is? It's gonna take a little while, xcode is pretty big)

Comment: it would also be helpful to see that "check logs for full command output". you can probably find it using the console application: https://www.howtogeek.com/356942/how-to-view-the-system-log-on-a-mac/

Comment: yes using pip install. Still have the problem. I wasn't be able find on console.

Comment: Is this your apple built-in python installation? there might be file permission issues. I always install a separate python for personal use at my user folder (I recommend anaconda on mac and winpython on PC).