# How to use pip3 install psycopg2?

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation, psycopg2

I ran into this ERROR when running "pip3 install psycopg2" on Mac.

I would like to install psycopg2 for the first time.

```
...
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
```

I tried pip, installing from GitHub. However, both failed.

Can someone help me, please? I really appreciate!

Comment: This could already been answered.
See the following topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304833/failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-macosx-using-virtualenv-and-pip

Comment: I tried all the proposed solutions! But did not work. I am still getting the same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed building wheel for psycopg2" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304833/failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-macosx-using-virtualenv-and-pip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install psycopg2 package through pip install... Is this because of Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767810/cant-install-psycopg2-package-through-pip-install-is-this-because-of-sierra)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpsycopg2%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Comment: I got things working finally from browsing the above links by: brew upgrade postgresql +
sudo pip install psycopg2   Thank you all for commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got things working from browsing the above links shared by these awesome people who commented on my post.

```
brew upgrade postgresql
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 4):

Just upgrade `psycopg2` version to 2.7.6 and it will work fine with `python3`:

```
pip3 install psycopg2==2.7.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing: Open terminal (editor or local)

```
$ brew install postgresql
$ brew services start postgresql
```

And go to sql promp for create a db (don't leave terminal):

```
$ psql postgres
```

> `CREATE DATABASE ..`
> `CREATE USER`
> `GRANT ...`