# Trouble finishing installation of psycopg2 on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2

it seems I can't install the psycopg2 requirement for a project I work on.
I am writing a Python2.7 code and I am working on the latest Mac OS.
I have the full error pasted here:
https://pastebin.com/7jK3PpSW

Here's an excerpt:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Google didn't really come up with anything helpful..
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Comment: Thanks! It helped!