# error install mysqlclient with pip, library not found for -lssl

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I am running mysql@8.x version on my MacOS, I have installed mysql and mysql-connector-o with brew. Currently brew link with mysql.

Running Django project on my python3 virtual env I am receiving following error -

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

and on installing the mysqlclient using pip, I am reciving following error

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/venv3/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-kf2fkhtc/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-qwpjjw3e/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Volumes/Samsung_T5/Work/python/repos/venv3/bin/../include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-kf2fkhtc/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: You are missing openssl libraries.

Comment: Also check [the PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) for any other prequisites and special notes for OsX

Comment: @jordanm thank you, with you pointing it out I took reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244687/6069796) and got it solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) pointed it out, the issue was exactly with the missing openssl libraries, for which I followed these steps to fix my issue -

1. Installing openssl

   ```
   brew install openssl
   ```
2. Now
        `pip install mysqlclient` should work.

   If it doesn't and still shows the same error `library not found for -lssl`, you could also try to link against brew's openssl:

   ```
   env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install mysqlclient
   ```

   if this still does not work, you might need to use the --no-cache option of pip, e.g.

   ```
   env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip --no-cache install mysqlclient
   ```

Answer (score 0):

After installing openssl via Homebrew I placed

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

in my .bash_profile and ran

```
source .bash_profile
```

and then

```
pip install mysqlclient
```