# Issue while installing psycopg2 in MacOS for Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 for Python 3.7 but I'm having a weird (and long) output issue.

I've tried to follow several stackoverflow replies but without success.

This is the code that I've tried.

`python3.7 -m pip install psycopg2`

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yl/jy_t4s4j6ld8y14kxs6_lg8c0000gn/T/pip-install-z93rthie/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/yl/jy_t4s4j6ld8y14kxs6_lg8c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-l54i7ghe --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
  psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1710:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
      ret = 1;
            ^
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1815:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               ^
  1 warning generated.
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1/include/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
  gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on how to approach this issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  For instance, have you tried installing using a different instance of `Python`, or a different version of `Python`?  Have you checked that `gcc` is actually installed on your system?  Have you looked into this `ld: library not found for -lssl` message?

Comment: I've tried installing postgresql, exporting the pg_config path and updating wheel and setup tools. Actually, psycopg2 is installed ok for python2.7. How can I chech gcc for a differente instance of python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpsycopg2%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+lssl

Comment: Or install [`psycopg2-binary`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/): `pip install psycopg2-binary`. The package [provides](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/#files) precompiled wheels for all major platforms and all supported Python version.

Comment: Thank you, installing the binary module worked for me. However, I'll have a look at the other links to understand why this issue came up for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the output, it looks like a dependency issue.

You have a couple options:

1. You can go through the output and try to install the missing dependencies
2. You can install the binary, but this isn't recommended for production
3. Or you can try installing a previous version of psycopg2

Trying this in a clean python 3.7 environment, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965400/19487726), what worked was specifying psycopg2 2.7.7:

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.7
```

Hope this helps!