# Unable to install psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, homebrew, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2 on my mac. I have python version 3.7.3 and postgres@10, I get a long error while trying to install using pip.

Downgrading Postgres, used python 2.7.3

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_1/rc9x28rn7tb3vlfw6jh6q_wx871j7m/T/pip-install-8q77mcag/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/_1/rc9x28rn7tb3vlfw6jh6q_wx871j7m/T/pip-record-m17mwi14/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1712:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1817:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100009 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/include/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.9/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_1/rc9x28rn7tb3vlfw6jh6q_wx871j7m/T/pip-install-8q77mcag/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/_1/rc9x28rn7tb3vlfw6jh6q_wx871j7m/T/pip-record-m17mwi14/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_1/rc9x28rn7tb3vlfw6jh6q_wx871j7m/T/pip-install-8q77mcag/psycopg2/
```

Comment: which pip version are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpsycopg2%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26288042/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56594112/7976758

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228387/10729870)

> I had OpenSSL installed from brew (`brew install openssl`).
>   The following worked for me:
>
> ```
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"  
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" 
> pip install psycopg2
> ```

Comment: After many tries, this helped.
Works for me on MacOS 10.14.6 with Python 3.8