# Python pip install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows, cmd

So I downloaded Python 32 bits 1st, then I did
`python -m pip install mysqlclient`.

I needed Visual C++ 2015, but I had them cuz my text editors is VSCode.
I uninstalled VSCode, installed Visual Studio Build Tools, and I am getting this errors whenever I do `python -m pip install mysqlclient`.One, cl.exe wasnt added to my path, so I did, but it still says

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

so I downloaded the wheel package for windows, as some other stackoverflow answer said. Whenever I run it, I get

I tried downloading Python 64 bits downloading the wheels, adding `cl.exe` to path.

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-o3ba369p' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\mysqlclient\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _mysql.c
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nk0ejlkz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Patrik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0vmm7fdx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nk0ejlkz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

It should just work and the package `mysqlclient` just be installed using pip so I can use it with django.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't an official wheel for the current release 1.4.4, and you are getting errors when you try to install from source.

Since you use 64-bit Python on Windows, you could install `1.4.2.post1`, because there is an official wheel for that version.

```
python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
```

Or, you could download an unofficial wheel from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient, which has wheels for the latest release for 32-bit and 64-bit Python on Windows. Unless you have a particular reason to use 32-bit Python, I suggest you use 64-bit.

For example, you could download `mysqlclient‑1.4.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` (Python 3.7 64-bit for Windows) then do:

```
python -m pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: OH.MY.GOD.Thank you.It took me 6 hours and nobody told me, it ran instantly.Thank you.Now I can finally run databases.

Comment: Additionally, DO NOT RUN "pip install ~" WITH VIRTUALENV. with virtualenv, I got errors for a hour. However, global installation succeed clearly.

Comment: @JayLim I’m not sure why you had problems with the virtual env. Perhaps using `python -m pip install` would have worked. In general, it’s a good practice to use a virtual env, so I wouldn’t advise installing packages globally.

Comment: I just discovered that this link is now broken.  I have relied on it for years.  Any idea what happened and if it is hosted elsewhere now?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/vcaibq/christoph_gohlkes_windows_wheels_site_is_shutting/

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar situation, and i did this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

afterward,  inside a virtual environment:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

and that was because, i had another problem with the instalation of:

```
pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

Comment: Apt installing `libmysqlclient-dev` fixed my issue! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pymysql` instead of `mysqlclient`

> Install pymysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

Modify your `init.py` file

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

You can start your project

Comment: in the top of settings.py  `import pymysql` and then `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

Comment: @AliAref, if you're using this import in settings.py that will be counted after init.py. The reason to use this import in init.py is that the init.py file works as a constructor in the relative module.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: I also faced this problem on a macOS, with the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
```

A solution (borrowed from this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26288042/1145905)) that worked for me was to fix the brew-installed openssl linking:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

For People using macOS,

```
$ brew install mysql pkg-config
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: For people using Linux

`$ sudo apt install mysql pkg-config`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on **AWS Ubuntu instance**

[for Mac Linux]: `$ sudo apt install mysql pkg-config build-essential python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

[for Mac users]: `brew install mysql pkg-config`

`$ pip3 install mysqlclient`

if you encountered with ConfigParser NoModuleError then only install below:

`$ pip install configparser`

`$ sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.10/configparser.py /usr/lib/python3.10/ConfigParser.py`