# Installing requirements.txt throws an error on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

The project was working perfectly until recently when I created a model for my database and tried to pip install requirement.txt.  I have done everything I know including modifying my `settings.py` to add the missing library, reinstalling `django` and `psycopg2`, all to no avail. Here's my `requirement.txt`:

```
tweepy==3.8.0
django
gunicorn
django-heroku
```

The error i'm getting:

```
 ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/apple/Downloads/font_text/python-getting-started/getting-started/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/tn/843ff_ns4j5ddf0fyc998v6c0000gn/T/pip-install-phi9wroh/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/tn/843ff_ns4j5ddf0fyc998v6c0000gn/T/pip-record-sc3y24vo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/apple/###/###/PROJECTFOLDER/getting-started/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tn/843ff_ns4j5ddf0fyc998v6c0000gn/T/pip-install-phi9wroh/psycopg2/
```

Comment: Have you used `pip install -r requirements.txt` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. That was what brought that error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long hours of searching and experimenting, I finally was able to solve the problem. But I'm still investigating on what really could have caused the error. Anyways, here's what fixed it

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
pip install psycopg2
```

I found it here: [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, you need to install the `openssl-devel` package on your system.

Comment: @DevMike01 probably libssl is not in your library path and need to set it manually

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall gcc , gcc-c++ and dependencies.

For python 2.7

```
$ sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
$ sudo yum -y install python-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
$ pip install "your python packet"
```

For python 3.4

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
$ pip install "your python packet"
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-compiling-and-installing-psycopg2