# Can't install Psycopg2 in virtual environment

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a django project connected to a Postgresql DB so I also need Psycopg2 package installed. For some reason, I am able to install this globally on my computer and will be able to run things properly, but when I try and install it in my virtual environment I get this long return of an error.

I only installed it globally for the sake of trying to narrow down the problem. I am able to install other packages in my environment without a problem. The specific problem occurs when I switch my DB settings from SQLite to PostgreSQL and it needs psycopg2.

I've also tried uninstalling PostgreSQL and installing it back in case this was installed wrong in some way, but no difference. I'm thinking it has to do with folder structure somewhere but do not have much of an idea of how to go about it or if this is a reasonable thought.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-install-y3pelxup/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-install-y3pelxup/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-record-eptfxahu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
     cwd: /private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-install-y3pelxup/psycopg2/
Complete output (151 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o
psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    ret = 1;
          ^
psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o
In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:82:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o
In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o
In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o
In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:29:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/aix_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o
In file included from psycopg/aix_support.c:29:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o
In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o
In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o
In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-install-y3pelxup/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-install-y3pelxup/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hw/c0r922014qg_k21_k_zmyg6h0000gn/T/pip-record-eptfxahu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/luis/Documents/Code/bradynce-crm/env/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The easiest solution might be to install the wheel: `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: The wheel is generally advised against. If you're just running it locally it's probably fine, but there is a better way, in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl - which this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)