# difficulty with psycopg2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: python, django, xcode, heroku, psycopg2

I have a finished simple django blog application that I am in the process of deploying to heroku.

I have a live application now, but my static css files weren't included. I think that I've identified (part of) the problem in my settings.py file where django_heroku is unable to be imported.

When i try to pip install django-heroku, I error out at the psycopg2:

```
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that I have homebrew installed and have up-to-date versions of gcc, openssl, and xcode.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try next?

Comment: Much more popular duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with psycopg2 and MacOS in the past. Have you tried to install the precompiled version?

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

That usually clears things up for me!