# Psycopg2 installation error on mac: command 'clang' failed with status 1

Tags: django, postgresql, macos, psycopg2

I can't install psycopg2 on my m1 Mac. I tried to reinstall openssl with brew. I tried a lot of thing but nothing changed. The error log is super long so I couldn't understand what is wrong. I am facing up with this error when I try to `pip install psycopg2` Waiting for your help.
Here is the full error log: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4jG

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` first.

Comment: Yeah I already did that

Comment: Does `pip install psycopg2-binary` work ?

Comment: nope same error occurs

Comment: I am still waiting for responses...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is happening because it seems to be having some problem with ssl. I used different answers from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl) to solve it for myself:

1. Install openssl if you don't have:

   `brew install openssl`
2. Check the path where openssl got installed using:

   `brew --prefix openssl`
3. Use output from above and add LD flag when running the pip command, for example in my case the output was `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1` so I did the following:

   `LDFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib" pip install psycopg2`

And that did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks a million... It works and you saved my couple of days. Thank you very much. You are the best.

Comment: No problem, happy to know it worked and saved you time. :)