Install psycopg2 failed on macOS Sonoma
I try to install psycopg2-binary 2.7.7 on my MacOs (Sonoma 14.5), but I encountered some errors on the build
# pip install psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
  Using cached psycopg2-binary-2.7.7.tar.gz (428 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2-binary
  Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [205 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-univeruniversal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/testsuniversal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg2/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_list.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/bytes_format.o
      In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/connection_int.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/connection_type.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/cursor_int.o
      psycopg/cursor_int.c:76:20: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->notuples = 1;
                         ^ ~
      1 warning generated.
      psycopg/cursor_int.c:76:20: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->notuples = 1;
                         ^ ~
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/cursor_type.o
      psycopg/cursor_type.c:110:18: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->closed = 1;
                       ^ ~
      psycopg/cursor_type.c:1917:20: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->notuples = 1;
                         ^ ~
      2 warnings generated.
      psycopg/cursor_type.c:110:18: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->closed = 1;
                       ^ ~
      psycopg/cursor_type.c:1917:20: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to a one-bit wide bit-field changes value from 1 to -1 [-Wsingle-bit-bitfield-constant-conversion]
          self->notuples = 1;
                         ^ ~
      2 warnings generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/error_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/green.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/libpq_support.o
      In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -39/psycopg/lobject_int.oI/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/microprotocols.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
      In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/notify_type.o
      In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
      In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
      ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
      static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/pqpath.o
      psycopg/pqpath.c:214:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      psycopg/pqpath.c:1903:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          ret = 1;
                ^
      psycopg/pqpath.c:2022:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings generated.
      psycopg/pqpath.c:214:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      psycopg/pqpath.c:1903:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          ret = 1;
                ^
      psycopg/pqpath.c:2022:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                      PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/user/projects/appliance/django/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
          while (interp->next)
                 ~~~~~~^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pystate.h:17:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct _is'
      struct _is;
             ^
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:690:24: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'
              interp = interp->next;
                       ~~~~~~^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pystate.h:17:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct _is'
      struct _is;
             ^
      2 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2-binary
Failed to build psycopg2-binary
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects



I tried to update to psycopg2-binary to 2.9 but I have another error
like snakecharmerb said, they have problem with my django version (is 2.2)
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC

So, I may need to use the current project version with psycopg2-binary 2.7.7.
Here's what I've done so far:
xcode-select --install

I follow an answer in another question but it didn't work for me :/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244687/20561293
and another method was
brew install openssl
brew --prefix openssl
LDFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" pip install psycopg2

here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684138/20561293
This method didn't work for me either (openssl@3)
If anyone have an idea :?

I copied almost the entire output, I'm limited in characters (30000 max)

For psycopg2-binary, this issue suggests that the problem may be in the code that is calling into psycopg2.

Yeah, I see the same post but actually I can't update django (2.2)

If you can't upgrade Django the solution seems to be to downgrade psycopg2 to 2.8.6. The change in psycopg2 timezone code happened in the jump from 2.8.6 --> 2.9.0

I want to use a more older version, psycopg2-binary 2.7.7
